# preprocess images with tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset or with read_csv option

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I am adding this summarization of my issue to make it easier to understand:
I want to do exactly what is done in the following tensorflow example:
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets

```
# Reads an image from a file, decodes it into a dense tensor, and resizes it
# to a fixed shape.
def _parse_function(filename, label):
  image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
  image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string)
  image_resized = tf.image.resize_images(image_decoded, [28, 28])
  return image_resized, label

# A vector of filenames.
filenames = tf.constant(["/var/data/image1.jpg", "/var/data/image2.jpg", ...])

# `labels[i]` is the label for the image in `filenames[i].
labels = tf.constant([0, 37, ...])

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
```

The only differences are: I read the data from CSV that has many more features and then I call the map method:

```
dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(file_pattern=CSV_PATH_TRAIN,
                                                    batch_size=2,
                                                    header=True,
                                                    label_name = 'label').map(_parse_function)
```

How does my _parse_function need to look like? How do I access the image path features, updates it to be an image presentation and return a modified numeric matrix feature of the image without changing anything at the other features?

thanks,
eilalan

**==================Here are my code tries:==================**

My code reads a CSV with feature columns and label. One of the features is image path, the others are strings.
The image path need to be processed into image numbers matrix.
I have tried doing so with the following options. In both ways tf.read_file fails with the input dimension error. 
My question is how to pass one image at a time into the map methods

```
def read_image_png_option_1(image_path, depth=3, scale=False):
  """Reads the image from image_path (tf.string tensor) [jpg image].
  Cast the result to float32 and if scale=True scale it in [-1,1]
  using scale_image. Otherwise the values are in [0,1]
  Reuturn:
      the decoded jpeg image, casted to float32
  """
  image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(
      tf.image.decode_png(tf.read_file(image_path), channels=depth),
      dtype=tf.float32)
  if scale:
      image = scale_image(image)
  return image

def read_image_png_option_2(features, depth=3, scale=False):
  """Reads the image from image_path (tf.string tensor) [jpg image].
  Cast the result to float32 and if scale=True scale it in [-1,1]
  using scale_image. Otherwise the values are in [0,1]
  Reuturn:
      the decoded jpeg image, casted to float32
  """
  image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(
      tf.image.decode_png(tf.read_file(features['image']), channels=depth),
      dtype=tf.float32)
  if scale:
      image = scale_image(image)
  features['image'] = image
  return features

def make_input_fn(fileName,batch_size=8, perform_shuffle=True):
  """An input function for training """
  def _input_fn():
    def  decode_csv(line):
      print('line is ',line)
      filename_col,label_col,gender_col,ethinicity = tf.decode_csv(line, 
                                                                   [[""]]*amount_of_columns_csv, 
                                                                   field_delim=",",
                                                                   na_value='NA',
                                                                   select_cols=None)
      image_col = read_image_png_option_1(filename_col)
      d = dict(zip(['image','label','gender','ethinicity'], [image_col,label_col,gender_col,ethinicity])), label
      return d

    ## OPTION 1:
#     filenames could be more than one
#    dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(filenames=fileName).skip(1).batch(batch_size).map(decode_csv)

    ## OPTION 2: 
    dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(file_pattern=CSV_PATH_TRAIN,
                                                    batch_size=2,
                                                    header=True,
                                                    label_name = 'label').map(read_image_png_option_2)
                                                    #select_columns=[0,1]) #[tf.string,tf.string,tf.string,tf.string])

    if perform_shuffle:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=256)
    return dataset
  return _input_fn()

train_input_fn = lambda: make_input_fn(CSV_PATH_TRAIN)
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=50)

eval_input_fn = lambda: make_input_fn(CSV_PATH_VAL)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(eval_input_fn)

feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("image",shape=(224,224)),  # here i need a pyhton method to transform
                   tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list("gender", ["ww","ee"]),
                   tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list("ethinicity",["xx","yy"])]

estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,hidden_units=[1024, 512, 256],warm_start_from=ws)

tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(estimator, train_spec=train_spec, eval_spec=eval_spec)
```

Error for option 2:
ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'ReadFile' (op: 'ReadFile') with input shapes: [2].

Error for option 1:
ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'ReadFile' (op: 'ReadFile') with input shapes: [?].

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you need to read the CSV file into dataset.

Then for each row in your CSV you can call your parse function.

```
def getInput(fileList):
    # returns a dataset containing list of filenames
    files = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(fileList)

    # Returs a dataset containing list of rows taken from all the files in file list.
    # dataset is filled dynamically and not all entries are read at once
    dataset = files.interleave(tf.data.TextLineDataset)

    # call parse function for each row
    # returned dataset will contain list of whatever the parse function is returning for the row
    # we want the image path to be converted to decoded image in parse function
    dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function, num_parallel_calls=8)
    # return an iterator for the dataset which will be used to get elements.
    return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

The parse function will be passed only one parameter that will be a single row from the CSV file. You need to decode the CSV and do further processing on each value.

Let's say you have 3 columns in your CSV each being a string.

```
def _parse_function(value):
    columns_default = [[""], [""], [""]]
    # this will be a tensor of columns in the row
    columns = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=columns_default,
            field_delim=',')
    col_names = ["label", "imagepath", "c3"]
    features = dict(zip(col_names, columns))
    for f, tensor in features.items():
        # process imagepath to decoded image
        if f == "imagepath":
            image_string = tf.read_file(tensor)
            image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string)
            image_resized = tf.image.resize_images(image_decoded, [28, 28])
            features[f] = image_resized
    labels = tf.equal(features.pop('label'), "1")
    labels = tf.expand_dims(labels, 0)
    return features, labels
```

Edit:

Explanation for comment:

1. Dataset object simply contains a list of elements. The elements can be tensors or a tuple of tensors etc. Tensor object can contain anything. It could represent a single feature, a single record or a batch of record. Further dataset API provide handy methods to manipulate the elements within.
   If you are using dataset with another API like estimator then they expect the dataset elements to be in specific format which is what need to return from our input function for eg.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#train

I have edited my code block above to describe what dataset object at each step will contain.

2. From what I understand is that you have image path as one of the field in your CSV and you want to convert that path into an actual decoded image which you will use as one of the feature.

   Since the image is going to be just one of the feature, you should not try to create a dataset using image files alone. Dataset object will include all your features at once.

So doing this would be incorrect:

```
files = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(ds['imagepath']) 
dataset = files.interleave(tf.data.TextLineDataset)
```

If you are using make_csv() function to read your csv then it will convert each row of your csv into one record where one record will contain list of all features, same as columns of csv.

So each element in the returned dataset should contain a single tensor containing all your features.

Here your image path will be one of the features. now you want to transform that image path to decoded image.

I suppose you can do it by applying a parse function to elements of dataset using map() function but it will be slightly tricky as all your features are already packed inside a single tensor.

Comment: Thank you for the response. my questions are:
1. How does the dataset values merged with ds features. see below input_fn (getInput): 
2. Is it required to pop the label if I use make_csv_dataset?
ds = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(CSV_PATH_TRAIN,label_name='label',header=True)
files = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(ds['imagepath'])
dataset = files.interleave(tf.data.TextLineDataset) #is c3 feature included?
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function,num_parallel_calls = 8)
# Return the dataset.
return ds
Many thanks, Eila